# Can we mount the windows network shared folder to linux or can we access network shared folder through jenkins?

Tags: linux, mount, windows

I have one windows network shared folder eg : //hhnetapp/data/files. So Can I access the same drive-through Jenkins? or Can I access the same from Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a CIFS/SMB share on linux:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=<username>,domain=<domain> //server/share /mount/directory
```

You'll need to correct package installed to do this, on ubuntu it's called `cifs-utils`

Comment: Getting error as: mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)